# Inject dependency into view via codebehind using UnityContainer

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a Silverlight application, where only few controls use MVVM. I haven't much time to moved all controls to mvvm, but I need inject some services into that controls.

Because some controls are being created by declaring them in XAML like:

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>
<MyControlWithoutMVVM/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I can't see an option to inject dependency using Constructor Injection.

But maybe I'm wrong and this is why I'm posting that question.

Is there any solution to do that?

My CompositionRoot is in ApplicationStartup methon on the App class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put elements in your XAML code there is no way you can use constructor injection because you don't control the instantiation of these objects.

You can either remove the elements creation from the XAML and have a look at

- [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) allows you to work based on your viewmodels and creates the views for you (viewmodel first) or it lets you work with your UI and resolves the viewmodels (view first).

or

- [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) allows you to compose your UI and put elements in regions while enabling you to create objects using DI.

or you can drop DI and switch to a ServiceLocator-like approach ([which I cannot recommend](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)).